# Why is $\text{End}_K(K) = K$, or, more generally, $\text{End}_D(D) = D^{\text{op}}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, modules

Let $K$ be a field and a vector space over itself, $D$ a division ring with a modul over itself, with its opposite ring $D^{\text{op}}$.

Why is then $\text{End}_K(K) = K$?
Or more general, why is $\text{End}_D(D) = D^{\text{op}}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say we treat $D$ as a left module over itself.

Consider the isomorphism $D^{op} \rightarrow \mathrm{End}_D(D)$ given by $d \mapsto [-\cdot d]$, where $[-\cdot d]$ is the map that takes $x \in D$ to $xd$.

It is not hard to see that

1. $[-\cdot d]$ is an endomorphism of $D$ as a left $D$-module,
2. $[-\cdot d_1]+[-\cdot d_2]=[-\cdot (d_1+d_2)]$,
3. $[-\cdot d_1] \circ [- \cdot d_2]=[- \cdot (d_2d_1)]$, $[-\cdot 1]=\mathrm{id}_D,$

i.e. the map above is a homomorphism of rings (notice that the condition 3. corresponds to the fact that the domain is $D^{op}$ and not $D$).

To check injectivity, look at the value of general $[-\cdot d]$ at $1$. To check surjectivity, take a general endomorphism $\varphi$ of $D$ over itself and compare $\varphi $ and $[-\cdot \varphi(1)]$ (here is danger of confusion: $\varphi(1)$ is not necessarily $1$...).

Also notice that the assumption that $D$ is a division ring wasn't needed anywhere, the whole thing will work for arbitrary ring.

**Also warning.** Similarly, you can prove that if one considers $D$ as a *right* module over itself (now with the map $d \mapsto [d\cdot-]$), then $D \simeq \mathrm{End}_D(D)$, without any "op". The seeming asymmetry comes from the fact that one needs to choose some convention regarding the order of composition of maps, i.e. regarding the multiplication in the ring $\mathrm{End}_D(D)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I think, I've got only one little question left: In your answer you found a isomorphism of $D^{\text{op}}$ and $\text{End}_D(D)$. But why can you say now, that they equal one another? Why is it $\text{End}_D(D)=D^{\text{op}}$ and not $\text{End}_D(D)\cong D^{\text{op}}$?

Comment: But wouldn't the third point rather be
$d_1 \circ [-\cdot d_2] = [- \cdot d_2d_1]$ and the identity?

Comment: 1) Of course $D^{op}$ and $\mathrm{End}_D(D)$ are different rings "set-theoretic-wise" - one consists of elements of $D$ and the other of some endomrphisms, so unless all elements of $D$ are given in the form of some endomorphisms, the equality cannot hold. What is meant by the statement is that the two objects can be identified (and rather naturally, as you can see). 
2)The symbol $d_1 \circ [-\cdot d_2]$ does not make good sense - what you can do is compose maps (i.e. multiplication in $\mathrm{End}_D(D)$), that's what here $\circ$ denotes.